# Can UPDATE statement be used as INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, where-clause

I'm using MYSQL and my tables are like below. what I need to do is to update `speciality_name` field in `specialities` table corresponding to `list_of_specialities` in `clinics` table but when I do it like
below

```
UPDATE clinics c
  LEFT 
  JOIN specialities s
    ON s.clinic_id = c.clinic_id
   SET s.speciality_name = concat_ws('',c.list_of_specialities,s.speciality_id)
 WHERE  s.clinic_id = c.clinic_id
```

my table looks like this

```
speciality_id   speciality_name     clinic_id
            6   data                16
```

since there is no `speciality_id` for other `list_of_specialities` I think I must insert others but I need it to be automatically inserted and what I really need is that the table to look like this

```
speciality_id   speciality_name     clinic_id
            6   data                16
            7   data2               16
            8   data3               16
            9   data4               16
           10   asdsads             16

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clinics` (
  `clinic_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clinic_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_of_specialities` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clinic_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `doctors` (
  `doctor_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `clinic_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `speciality_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`doctor_id`),
  KEY `Doctor_FKIndex1` (`clinic_id`),
  KEY `Doctor_FKIndex2` (`speciality_id`),
  KEY `Doctor_FKIndex3` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `specialities` (
  `speciality_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `speciality_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clinic_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`speciality_id`),
  KEY `Speciality_FKIndex1` (`clinic_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: No. But an INSERT can be used as an UPDATE

Comment: Select between [REPLACE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) and [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: thanks @akina now it works with a little change to `speciality_name` field. It should be a `UNIQUE INDEX`. and for this problem I used `REPLACE` statement.

Comment: @keivanshirkoubian Remember - while unique index violation REPLACE deletes old violated record and inserts new one. So the query must mention all table fields (maybe except ones which must obtain defult values).

Comment: @akina I know what you mean since in that table there is just `speciality_id` which is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and don't get updated I think there shouldn't be a problem in mentioning all fields and in my answer I replaced both `speciality_name` and `clinic_id`.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with a little change to `speciality_name` field. it should be a `UNIQUE INDEX` and `REPLACE` statement must be used. here is an example:

```
REPLACE 
INTO specialities
SET speciality_name = 'data1', clinic_id = '16'
```